# Get data clubbed from Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get data organized in a certain manner. Here is what I'm trying to do

I have a table in Redshift from which we are trying to get the following output

Table: foo

```
e1 | c1 | c2
1  | 1  | 2
1  | 3  | 4
1  | 5  | 7
1  | 9  | 15
2  | 3  | 4
2  | 7  | 8
```

We are trying to club all the rows where difference between previous row c2 next row c1 is less than 1

Desired Output

```
e1 | c1 | c2
1  | 1  | 7
1  | 9  | 15
2  | 3  | 4
2  | 7  | 8
```

Current Output

```
e1 | c1 | c2
1  | 1  | 4
1  | 3  | 7
2  | 3  | 4
2  | 7  | 8
```

I have tried doing CTE. Here is the queries I'm working on. I get the results that are isolated, or with

CTE:

```
with es as(
select *
from foo
where e1 not in (SELECT t1.e1
  FROM foo as t1 
  inner join foo as t2
  on t1.e1=t2.e1 and (t2.c1-t1.c2)=1)
union all
SELECT t1.e1
      ,t1.c1
      ,isnull(t2.c2, t1.c2) as c2
  FROM foo as t1 
  inner join foo as t2
  on t1.e1=t2.e1 and (t2.c1-t1.c2)=1 
 )
 select * from es
 where e1 is not null
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you meant "We are trying to club all the rows where difference between previous row c2 next row c1 is less than 1 **where e1 is the same**".

You could use [Window Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html) for that. [LEAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html) would give you the following c1 (provided ordering is right), and then you can filter on that:

```
SELECT
  e1,
  c1,
  c2
FROM (
       SELECT
         e1,
         c1,
         c2,
         LEAD(c1, 1)
         OVER (PARTITION BY e1
           ORDER BY e1 ASC, c1 ASC, c2 ASC) AS lead_c1
       FROM so_test
       ORDER BY e1 ASC, c1 ASC, c2 ASC) AS with_lead
WHERE lead_c1 - c2 != 1 OR lead_c1 IS NULL
```

Output:

```
e1|c1|c2
1 |5 |7
1 |9 |15
2 |3 |4
2 |7 |8
```

Without internal knowledge of the table structure, I had to order by all columns to ensure the rows are in the same order as you posted. If you have another key (like sort key), better use that.

If my assumption about **where e1 is the same** is wrong, remove "PARTITION BY e1".

Comment: The answer is not complete but I understood the approach. Thanks @denismo